# Website broken in Firefox (works in chrome+safari) + Meyers Reset

Tags: html, css

my friend was helping me make a new design for my website but has since gotten a full time job. Web Design is not my strong suit and I can't get it to work across all browsers!

So right now, my website looks good in Chrome and Safari. But is broken in FireFox
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22866203/sb%202/speedbump.html
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22866203/sb%202/speedbump.css

I was researching/trying different CSS Resets to fix this problem (Meyers Reset) but this only seemed to break the page in Chrome and Safari as well.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

If you started without a reset then a reset is not going to help. You particular problem is that you're not clearing your floats. To solve it do this:

```
#social-media, hr { clear: both; }
```

Btw, you have a 404 error on an image and many other warnings. Check firebug or devtools.

Answer (score 1):

As I was messing a bit with your site with firebug, I noticed that if you add to some divs the property `float: left` it arranges the site to look like it does in chrome.
Download FireBug for firefox (great tool) and arrange the floating divs exactly how you want them to be.

Hope it helps.

Comment: elclanrss answer is better, take it. (:

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Give the #wrapper overflow:hidden and remove margin top from previous and after divs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have floated elements in the body text (left) and the green box (right) but the parent isn't floated, meaning that the floated elements will not affects it's overall height. Also, don't use hr, instead, use borders.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/33811812/stackoverflow/speedbump/Speedbump.html

The paths are now relative to my folder and you'll need to change them back.

Answer (score 0):

**IDs** need to be unique(#wrapper) I see four ( 4 ) instances of it from the image above.

Use a class instead as it can be re-used.

```
.wrapper:after{
    visibility: hidden;
    height:0;
    display: block;
    clear:both;
    *zoom:1;
    content: '.';
}
```